# Pandas add cell background color using list and save to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have dataframe as below.
[image]

I want to change background color by condition and finally I want to save to excel.
There are some cases as follow:

- condition 1: exact match & case sensitive=False --> red
- condition 2: contain & case sensitive=False --> yellow
- condition 3: repeat same character 3 more --> blue
- list_for_condition1 = [us, ca]
- list_for_condition1 = [apple, sam]
- list_for_condition3 = [xxx, xxxx, xxxxxxxxxxx, bbb, aaa]

This is expected output.
[image]

I found below code using stype.applymap but couldn't apply this case.

```
styled = (df.style.applymap(lambda v: 'background-color: %s' % 'green' if v=='col' else ''))
styled.to_excel('d:/temp/styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would define a separate function reflecting your conditions and `applymap`:

```
def colorize(x):
    try:
        lower = x.lower()
        # condition 1, pass the corresponding list
        if lower in ['us','ca']: return 'background-color: red'

        # condition 2
        for s in ['apple', 'sam']: 
            if s in lower: return 'background-color: yellow'

        # condition 3
        for s in ['xxx','bbb', 'aaa']:
            if s in lower: return 'background-color:  blue'

        return ''
   except:
        return ''

# toy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['USA','us','usa','ca', 'CA'],
                   'V1':["Apple", "Applex", 'APPLE', 'SAMSUNG','xxx'],
                   'V2':['Samsung', 'Semsung', 'SamSung1', 'apple', 'bbbb'],
                   'V3':['SAMSUNG', 'SS','APPLEXX', 'APPLEs', 'aaa']
                   })

df.style.applymap(colorize)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: I saw that coming. See update with `try:.. except:`.

Comment: error occurred ( 'int' object has no attribute 'lower') and 'CA' in Country Column not change background color.

Comment: For reference, you did say `case sensitive`, which means `'ca' != 'CA'`. Anyway, see update.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I means case sensitive=False. Thank you for your inform.